# Facebook won't let me publish a past action

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

here's Facebook's answer:

{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"The action you are trying to publish is invalid because the 'start_time' you provided of '1325770789' is more than '86400' seconds in the past."}}

I tried all combinations : with/wo start_time, end_time, expires.... always fails

any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to publish with a date that is no more than 86400 seconds in the past?

Comment: Hi HElmut, it was a bug on FB api that has been solved - alles klar!